# CSV Empty Column Handling - Fast CSV npm

Tags: node.js, csv, parsing, npm, unexpected-token

I have a CSV with 5 columns, few of which might be empty for some records.

For example, lets say

[image]

Here, Subject and Marks are empty for Rib.
In this case, iff I try to parse the CSV file using npm module **[fast-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv)**, it throws an error

> ...
>
> > Rib,3,,,
> >
> > > SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Code Snippet :

```
'use strict';

var csvFormatter = require('fast-csv')
var filePath = process.argv[2],
  data = [];

csvFormatter.fromPath(filePath, {
  headers: true
}).on('data', function (d) {
  data.push(d);
}).on('end', function () {
    console.log(data);
    process.exit(0);
  });
```

Is there any option to set a default value for columns or to handle this exception in any other way, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add your code, where you read and parse the csv.

Comment: This code and a csv I created from the picture, works perfectly for me. Maybe post a sample of your csv that reproduces this error.